# Symfony Redirect for some action

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, routes, twig

I use this [dashboard](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/table_editable.html) and when I pushed button "Add New" create dynamics button save, I find this button in js file this dasboard:

```
 function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        jqTds[0].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
        jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
        jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[4] + '">';
        jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[5] + '">';
        jqTds[6].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[6] + '">';
        jqTds[7].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[7] + '">';
        jqTds[8].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="??????????">Save</a>';
        jqTds[9].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="?????????">Cancel</a>';
    }
```

and my question 
I have routing for add new developer how I put my routing this "href=" or maybe redirect for my creatAction ????

Comment: why arent you using a form?

Comment: I using table.html.twig and this twig use plugins js snd this js I have button Save and I need if pushed button fo to the my symfony routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use that way,

put hidden input and then get value via jQuery

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="form-url" val="{{ path('my_route') }}">
```

in edit row fundtion

```
jqTds[9].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="'+$('#form-url').val();+'">Cancel</a>';
```

Comment: I have html.twig where I need post this `<input type="hidden" id="form-url" val="{{ path('my_route') }}"> ? ` in hmlt twig ?

Comment: solved, very simple ) BUT NEDD `<input type="hidden" id="form-url" value="{{ path('my_route') }}">`